# fixing element position in an asp.net application view

Tags: .net, css, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have an asp.net application in which i have a style problem . in a view i have this snippet:

```
 @if (Model[0] > 5)
     {
         @Html.ActionLink("<<<<", "Projects_Management", new { inc = Model[0] - 5 }, new {@class="previous"})
     }

     @if (Model[0] < 5 * Model[2])
     {
     @Html.ActionLink(">>>>", "Projects_Management", new { inc = Model[0] + 5 }, new {@class="nextIcon"})
     }
```

the **CSS**

```
.previous
{
     margin-left:10px;
     background: url('../images/previousIcon.png') no-repeat border-box right;
     display: block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 50px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
.nextIcon
{

        margin-left:80%;
     background: url('../images/nextIcon.png') no-repeat border-box right;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 50px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */

}
```

but i have this result:

[image]

the link [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lamloumi/8THyc/)

the two links aren't in the same line.  So what is the problem: Why they aren't in the same line? How can i fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.previous` class has `display: block` style, replace it with `inline-block` just like `.next` class

Comment: Sir, please provide jsfiddle link to your case

Comment: That's not the same result. the left button is now on the next line, rather than the right button. A solution would be to remove the margin-left:80% and add float:right to the right button.